# Hbase shell warning: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available

Tags: shell, hadoop, hbase

Hi I have been configuring Hbase 0.96 compatible with Hadopp 2.2. Previously I had versions hbase-0.94.11 and hadoop-1.2.1. I did as per documentation and my previous expierence. Now when logging to hbase shell in 0.96 I get following warning:
hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available

I tried to fix this with http://balanceandbreath.blogspot.com/2013/01/utilnativecodeloader-unable-to-load.html
And I'm trying to through http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html
But I cannot digest it. I reckon there should be less invasive way of directing hadoop libraries onto correct ones. I don't recall setting variable like that in previous cofniguration.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Hadoop Native Libraries Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html) you mention in your post, it says:

> Either download a hadoop release, which will include a pre-built version of the native hadoop library, or build your own version of the native hadoop library.

I was able to get around this message by including the Hadoop 2.2 library as an explicit dependency in my project.  Using maven, this worked for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```